# How to fix scanner while error

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, console, java.util.scanner

Back again with CacheScript, this time an easier question.
Here is the problem code:

```
while (open.hasNext() == true) {
                String code = open.nextLine();
                if (code.equals("CacheScript")) {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Package Successfully Loaded.");
                   txtBar.setText("Cache Script 2014");
                }
                if (code.equals("cache.color.orange")) {
                    map.setBackground(Color.orange);
                }                    
            }
```

For some reason, when I run this, the scanner (open) does not follow through... How can I fix the while code so each line can be tested to see if it equals one of the commands?

Comment: You can simply say `while (open.hasNext())` instead of `while (open.hasNext() == true)`

Comment: Thanks! What about the repeat? It still won't work for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
while (open.hasNext() == true) {

            if (code.equals("CacheScript")) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Package Successfully Loaded.");
               txtBar.setText("Cache Script 2014");
            }
            if (code.equals("cache.color.orange")) {
                map.setBackground(Color.orange);
            }
        String code = open.nextLine();
        continue;
        }
```

Comment: Your welcome, and if it's helpful, please upvote the comment :)